# ajax request overwrite everytime my json file

Tags: php, ajax, json

I try to save my JSON datas to a file, but it saves only the last request (I think everytime overwrite my general.json file). I would like to add all requests to general.json.  Where is the problem in my codes?

the ajax part of tomorrow.php:

```
   $(document).ready(function () {

        var json = mg;
        for (var i = 0; i < json.length; i++) {

           $.ajax({
              type:"GET",
              url:"save_json.php",
              contentType: "application/json",
              dataType: "json",
              async: false,
              data: { data: JSON.stringify({
                  country: json[i][0],
                  competition: json[i][1],
                  club: json[i][2]}) },


              success: function(){ alert("data")},
              error: function(){ /*alert("error")*/}
            });
        }
    });
```

And the save_json.php:

```
  <?php
    $myFile = "general.json";
    $fh = fopen($myFile, 'w') or die("can't open file");
    $stringData = $_GET["data"];
    fwrite($fh, $stringData);
    fclose($fh)

    ?>
```

and the content of the general.json file:

```
 {"country":"America","competition":"Copa Americ","club":"Boca Juniors"}
```

Why saved only the last request? How can I save all my request without overwrite everytime general.json file?

Answer (score 0):

Replace this :

```
$fh = fopen($myFile, 'w') or die("can't open file");
```

With this :

```
$fh = fopen($myFile, 'a') or die("can't open file");
```

"w" option erases what was previously in the file.
"a" option appends the new content at the end of the file (and conserves what was there before).

EDIT

To store a valid json string, proceed as follows :

```
<?php
$json = json_decode(file_get_contents("general.json")); // here you store the decoded content of your file in a variable
$json[] = $_GET["data"]; // You append the new data to the variable
file_put_contents("general.json", json_encode($json)); // And then, you encode the whole data and put it inside the file.
```

Here are link to documentation about file_*_contents functions (they replace fopen, fwrite and fclose) :

- [file_get_contents](http://php.net/manual/en/function.file-get-contents.php)
- [file_put_contents](http://php.net/manual/en/function.file-put-contents.php)

Comment: This will result in invalid JSON: `{ "a": 1 }` is okay, `{ "a": 1 }{ "b": 2 }` is not. JSON is not appendable. If OP wants to have an array of all responses in the JSON file (e.g. `[{ "a": 1 }, { "b": 2 }]`), one proper way is to load it, append to the array, then save it back, or as a hack for speed, to seek to write before the last `]`; if not, he should clarify what he wants.

Comment: @Amadan: and what can I do now?

Comment: My current json file format:  {"country":"America","competition":"Copa Americ","club":"Boca Juniors"}  {"country":"Europa","competition":"Bundesliga","club":"Hannover"}  {"country":"Asia","competition":"JLeague","club":"Nagoya"}   this is wrong format?

Comment: Yes, it is. Just like two apples smushed together are not one big apple, two JSON smushed together are not a bigger JSON.

Comment: I edited my answer to provide a way to generate a valid json format.

Comment: @Heru-Luin: And where must I put these three rows? Into a new php?

Comment: Sorry for my question but I am beginner

Comment: Or you write it with a new line and reads it line by line at the end. I would not prefere to read all the time the full json, only to prepend it valid. I see a big performance problem when there are many entries.

Comment: This code is meant to replace the PHP code you gave in the question (save_json.php).

Comment: the current json format after I replaced my code to your code at save_json.php: ["{\"country\":\"America\",\"competition\":\"Copa Americ\",\"club\":\"Boca Juniors,\"}",  this is valid json now?

Comment: yes, it saved but this is the current format, is it valid json?  ["{\"country\":\"America\",\"competition\":\"Copa Americ\",\"club\":\"Boca Juniors,\"}",

Comment: Looks like half a json string. Did you post the entire file content ?

Comment: No, just the content of the first request.

Comment: Post the whole content of the file, we'll tell you if it's ok :)

Comment: I don't know that it is a valid json format? Because I view this site and I don't see similar format what I fave: http://json.org/example

Comment: http://jsonviewer.stack.hu/ paste you json on this website and click on viewer. It will tell you if there are errors. If not, it will show you the structure of the JSON string.

Comment: You are welcome. Do not hesitate to mark the question as answered.

Answer (score 0):

1. You have used the wrong mode for appending data into the file.You have opened the file in write mode instead of append mode.
2. Open the file in append mode so your contend will be appended on the present file code.
   Replace this line:

> $fh = fopen($myFile, 'w') or die("can't open file");

with:

```
$fh = fopen($myFile, 'a') or die("can't open file");
```

Comment: thanks, I already done this earlier, but experts said it produced wrong json format at my file